# Laravel validate request as a whole

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I would like to validate given lecture. There are some validation rules but I want to extend it somehow with validation function which takes 3 attributes as arguments and check others lectures in database and return valid if none of lectures overlap. Lectures have start, end DateTime attributes.

Validation function is

```
private function noOtherLecturesOnGivenTime($start, $end, $hall)
{
    if(!$start instanceof Carbon) {
        $start = new Carbon($start);
    }

    if(!$end instanceof Carbon) {
        $end = new Carbon($end);
    }

    if(is_null($hall)) {
        return true; // if there is no hall defined, all times are acceptable
    }

    if(!$hall instanceof Model) {
        /** @var Hall $hall */
        $hall = Hall::find($hall);
    }
    $overlappingLectures = $hall->lectures()->get()->filter(function ($lecture) use ($start, $end) {
        // (Ts < e) and (Te > s)
        return $start->lt($lecture->end) and $end->gt($lecture->start);
    });

    return $overlappingLectures->count() === 0;
}
```

I don't know how and where to put this function so Laravel's validator throws exception and I could specify error message with i18n.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation about custom validation rules.

From creating the rule to specifiying error messages, there is a full exemple there :

> [Laravel custom validation rules documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules)

For your case, you can fetch the parameters from the request in the validation method.

I think the validation rule will still occur even if other parameters aren't set, don't forget to check if they are in the request

Comment: I was reading that, but I would like to give it to neither attribute of request. I want to run that function after all validation rules are validated. But I don't want to format 422 - Unprocessable Entity myself(so after validation hooks are not applicable).

Comment: You're passing `$end` `$end` `$hall` through the request right? Just get your request in the custom validation rule to fetch your parameters and use your function